# Python: include entries of a dictionary in the local namespace of a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, namespaces, local

This has probably been asked before, but a quick search didn't give me an answer.

Suppose there is a dictionary containing all variables. How can I pass this dictionary on to the local namespace of a function? For example:

```
data = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
def f(data):
    return data['a'] + data['d']
```

requires to write data[' '] around each variable you would like to access. How can you add all entries of the dictionary to the local namespace of the function? For objects you can use

```
self.__dict__.update(data)
```

Is there something equivalent for functions, so that you get something along the lines of:

```
data = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
def f(data):
    add_to_local_namespace(data)
    return a + d
```

Comment: The question I have is why? This seem very un-pythonic. If you want their values, why not pass the dictionary index as a parameter instead?

Comment: @DylanLawrence The dictionary will also be used as input for a class object further on in the function. As there are quite a few variables used in the class I don't want to write all of them down explicitly when creating the object. As I'm calling these functions from another module which contains the input, I need to pass all of the input on.

Comment: dictionary is an mutable object, what ever you change inside the function will reflect the original, as in python its pass by object reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible in the general case, because the dict can have keys which are not valid variable names, e.g. Python [keywords](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ca1b66fd059758bbd6e2cc62c8f2adecefe8f942/Lib/keyword.py#L15) or non-strings.

If you desperately need this, and you can guarantee that the dict keys are all valid variable names, *and you don't need it to work on Python 3*, it's possible to loop over the dict items and use an `exec` statement.  There are some weird scoping consequences of this approach, it's very ugly, and should be strongly discouraged.

An acceptable alternative is to create a dummy object and set them as attributes, for example:

```
>>> data = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> v = SimpleNamespace(**data)
>>> v.a
1
>>> v.d
4
```

But it's only really like a syntactic sugar for dict access.  **Read zen of Python #19**.  Whichever way you look at it, you will need namespacing!

Another idea: create a callable class instead of a function (by inheriting `collections.Callable`), and unpack the dict into attributes on the class.  Then at least your variables will be namespaced by the class.

Comment: This is probably the most appropriate solution, since it doesn't require evil hacks or writing down all variables used in the function explicitly.

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea. +1. I think you still may need to be careful about mutable objects though.

Comment: Here's evidence: `import argparse; d = {'a': [1]}; o = argparse.Namespace(**d); o.a.append('no no no no no'); d['a']` which returns `[1, 'no no no no no']`